# Why does head change in this Linked List?

Tags: linked-list

Why does the head change here?

I thought assigning oddPointer to head would allow me to traverse through the list without changing head.  This does not seem to be the case.  When I log(head) it appears as 1->3->5, why is it not 1->2->3->4->5?

Is there a way to complete this without changing head?

```
// JavaScript
var oddEvenList = function (head) {
    let oddList = new ListNode(-1);
    let oddCopy = oddList;

    let cnt = 0;
    let oddPointer = head;

    while (oddPointer) {
        cnt++;
        if (cnt % 2 !== 0) {
            oddList.next = oddPointer;        // -1,1,3,5
            oddList = oddList.next;
        }
        oddPointer = oddPointer.next;
    }
    console.log(oddList);
    console.log(oddCopy);

    console.log(head);
    console.log(oddPointer);

    return -1;
}

function ListNode(val, next) {
    this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
    this.next = (next === undefined ? null : next)
}

let a1 = new ListNode(1);
let a2 = new ListNode(2);
let a3 = new ListNode(3);
let a4 = new ListNode(4);
let a5 = new ListNode(5)
a1.next = a2;
a2.next = a3;
a3.next = a4;
a4.next = a5;

console.log(oddEvenList(a1));
```

Comment: It looks like other than `oddList` itself, your various lists share nodes between them, meaning that modifying the nodes in one list may affect other lists as well. Your code will probably need to be revised to account for this (keeping in mind the difference between references and values).

Comment: I see, thank you.  I thought when I created the oddList and made the oddList.next = oddPointer, I have two different lists.  

You are saying they are sharing nodes, thereby when I eventually change the oddList.next value of a shared node I am changing the next value of a node in the head correct?

So the "head" that comes into the function is a reference to the original list and not a copy of the original list?

Comment: Although I might quibble with the language a bit, what you say above sounds more or less correct. The 'head' argument is a reference to the head of the original list, not a copy of it. Therefore, as you said, you're essentially passing in the original list and not a copy. The topics involved (values and references, shallow and deep copies, etc.) are too much for a comment, but I think what you said above indicates that you're on the right track with respect to figuring it out.

Comment: Great, thank you.  Can you suggest some resources on these topics?  Can you suggest any topics related to LinkedLists?  I am non-traditionally educated in these topics and am looking to improve my education.

Comment: Just the usual - Google, articles, books, etc. Probably mostly just doing what you're doing now though - try to implement something, deal with problems as they come up, and learn as you go :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep working.